# Flutter: local_auth can be bypassed by pressing the back button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) for user verification.

The root widget of my app is a `stateless` widget.

The bug:
The authentication screen pops up as usual. If the fingerprint (or pin) matches, the user can then access the app. However, if the back button is pressed (while the authentication screen is still up), the authentication window vanishes and the user can access the app without authenticating.

I'm using `Flutter-2.5.3` and `local_auth-1.1.8`.

This is the `main.dart`:

```
//other imports here
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  var localAuth = LocalAuthentication();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  if (prefs.getBool('auth') == true) {
    await localAuth.authenticate(
        localizedReason: 'Authenticate to access Notes',
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        stickyAuth: true,);
  }

  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then((_) {
    runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //returns my widget
  }
}
```

I tried moving the `runApp` block under a conditional, such that the main root window gets called only when the authentication was successful. However the result remained the same.
This was what I did:

```
if (prefs.getBool('auth') == true) {
    var authenticate = await localAuth.authenticate(
        localizedReason: 'Authenticate to access Notes',
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        stickyAuth: true,);
    if (authenticate == true) {
      await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then((_) {
        runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Changing `MyApp` to a `StatefulWidget`.
2. Adding an awaited function that attempts to authenticate the user before the user can access the widget (that is, the build function).

Modifying the code:

```
//other imports here
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //removing the authentication block from the main method
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then((_) {
    runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {  //changing MyApp to StatefulWidget
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _authenticate();  //the function that handles authentication
  }

  void _authenticate() async {
    var localAuth = LocalAuthentication();

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (prefs.getBool('auth') == true) {
      var authenticate = await localAuth.authenticate(
        localizedReason: 'Authenticate to access Notes',
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        //Not using stickyAuth because:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83773
        // stickyAuth: true,
      );
      if (authenticate != true) 
        exit(0);  //exiting the app if the authentication failed
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //returns my widget
  }
}
```